# How do I install Windows Server 2012 R2 alongside Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, bootloader, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install Windows Server 2012 R2, purely for educational reasons, on my laptop. I had tried to use Virtualbox but I cannot use hyper-v (which is essential for the course I am following) within a virtualized server. After some Googling I came to the conclusion that you can't virtualize in a virtualisation.

**My current situation:**

I have Windows 7 installed and Ubuntu 14.04. My laptop uses the boot-loader of Ubuntu. So when I start up I have to choose between Ubuntu or Windows. Now I made a new partition of 300GB by shrinking some of the disk size of my Windows 7 partition. Did shrink it within Windows 7 Disk Mananger. I also have an ISO file of the Windows Server 2012 R2 that I need to install and a valid (student) key for activation.

**What I want to do:**

I want to install Windows Server 2012 R2 on the new partition of 300GB that I made. But I am not sure how to approach this. Should I install it from within Windows 7 or Ubuntu? Keep in mind that I am using Ubuntu's boot-loader to select the operating system on start-up. Maybe I can add it later to the boot-loader, but I wouldn't know how. Or should I burn the ISO file to a disk or put it on an USB stick and configure in my BIOS to start-up from USB or DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would need to download boot-repair from [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and install in onto a usb or cd/dvd. Then install Windows server R2. Once you have done that boot off your usb and repair boot menu. boot-repair tool lets you view grub config it might be a good idea to make a copy of config. As when you run boot-repair tool it might only pick up Windows Server 2012 R2. If you backup config you will have a copy of Windows 7 config. Merge the two configurations together and you have a triple boot menu.

Comment: I managed to install Windows Server 2012 R2 but now Windows Boot Manager (WBM) took over control at booting (as expected). It only shows Windows Server and Windows 7. It doesn't show my Ubuntu so I can't access it. My DVD-player doesn't work and tried booting from USB but that also doesn't work. (I've heard some USB-sticks are not able to be made into a bootable USB-stick?) I tried Grub2Win (installed while in Windows 7) but I still get to see the WBM. I managed to get Grub2 in the WBM menu and when I select it I get the right interface but when I select an OS I get send back the the WBM.

Comment: If you have Grub2 menu come up first with the option of ubuntu or WBM it should should work.